# How do I bring back N-panel tabs wheel scroll?

Tags: interface, mouse

I've been using Blender 3.0.1 for a long time and finally decided to upgrade to the latest version. I have imported my previous preferences, everything else seemed fine, but to my despair I've noticed that I can no longer scroll through the tabs of the N-panel with my mouse wheel as I did all the time in ver. 3.0.1 (hovering over the tabs and scrolling up and down to switch between  them accordingly). I've tried both ver. 4.0.1 and 3.6 LTS.

[image]

Did the developers get totally rid of this feature or it should just be turned on somewhere?

I have chronic finger pains, so every extra click counts and this is really a big deal for me. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried with both mouse wheel and track pad, all is working fine apparently (v4.0 under Windows 10). So there is something else for your case?

Comment: Thanks for checking! It's reassuring that it actually should work, but I can't seem to understand what could cause this problem in my case. I've got Win 10 too, I've tried reboot, reinstalling Blender to another drive, loading factory settings - nothing helps. Both wheel and track pad work in ver. 3, but none works in 3.6 and 4

Comment: I'm sorry but as I can not reproduce this issue, I can not help. In hope someone else will provide a solution...

Comment: *ctrl-wheel_scroll* for me. unfortunately I don't see anything in key-mappings to change this

Comment: @james_t same here. It's *wheel* up until 3.5.1, but In 3.6.0 onwards it's *Ctrl wheel*.

Comment: @L0Lock -- damn those pesky developers !  ;-)

Comment: Interesting. I'm on Windows 10 and in either 3.65 or 4.01, I don't need press Ctrl to scroll with the mouse.

Comment: @james_t oh, I didn't know about ctrl+wheel either, I thought it was going to be a mouse click each time, but this way it's a bit more tolerable. Than you!

Comment: We had this question here already, there the asker contacted and they said it is intentionally changed, not a bug and there is no option to change it. The funny thing is, there was someone who said it still worked for him without `Ctrl` just like @curious_1 did, now I wonder how this is possible for them when it is a deliberate change in recent versions without the option to change it back...? There was another one saying not to use `Ctrl`, but he misunderstood what we were talking about.

Comment: As usual, I should have read the question more closely. The OP said"scrolling up and down to **switch** between them". I missed the switch between part. As @james_t said and as is demonstrated here: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/113664 to switch between tabs it's Ctrl + <scroll>. One can scroll the tabs without switching between them with <scroll>.